# How to load JSON array data into UIActionSheet button title using Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have `JSON` data within `array`. This array data I need to load into `UIActionSheet` button `title`. Here, I tried to create a common UIActionSheet with single `button`. Based on array strings I need to load data as a button title. I am sure, I never get above 4 array index from JSON, So I would like to load it into action sheet and based on click to get id value. I don’t know how to load it, as a button title.

**My JSON Codable**

```
   // MARK: - Welcome
struct Welcome: Codable {
    let status: Bool
    let data: DataClass
}

// MARK: - DataClass
struct DataClass: Codable {
    let id, rollnum, osname, dataDescription: String
    let team: [Team]
    let record, score: [String]
    let titles: [Title]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, rollnum, osname
        case dataDescription = "description"
        case team, record, score, titles
    }
}

// MARK: - Team
struct Team: Codable {
    let name, group: String
}

// MARK: - Title
struct Title: Codable {
    let status, id, icon: String
}
```

**JSON Decoder**

```
var titleData = [Title]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.loadJSON()
}

// MARK: JSON Data Load

func loadJSON(){
    let urlPath = ""
    let url = NSURL(string: urlPath)
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: url! as URL) { data, response, error in
        guard data != nil && error == nil else {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        do {
            let decoder = try JSONDecoder().decode(Welcome.self,  from: data!)
            self.titleData = decoder.data.titles
        } catch { print(error) }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

**Objective C Sample Need to change Swift 5**

```
NSArray *array = @[@"1st Button",@"2nd Button",@"3rd Button",@"4th Button"];

    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title Here"
                                                             delegate:self
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                               destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                    otherButtonTitles:nil];

    // ObjC Fast Enumeration
    for (NSString *title in array) {
        [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:title];
    }

    actionSheet.cancelButtonIndex = [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];

    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
```

**Exact Output**

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just loop and add action to ActionSheet

```
@IBAction func ClickAction(_ sender: Any) {

    let actionSheetAlertController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    for title in self.titleData {
      let action = UIAlertAction(title: title.status, style: .default) { (action) in
        print("Title: \(title.id)")
      }

      let icon = UIImage.init(named: title.icon)

      action.setValue(icon, forKey: "image")
      action.setValue(CATextLayerAlignmentMode.left, forKey: "titleTextAlignment")

      actionSheetAlertController.addAction(action)
    }

    let cancelActionButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
    actionSheetAlertController.addAction(cancelActionButton)

    self.present(actionSheetAlertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
```

Comment: fantastic solution btw I need to show title.status instead of title.id, when user click the button need to print its title.id, is it possible.

Comment: Also different resourceName: "\(title.icons)" icon names I need to use. its also based on JSON response.

Comment: @myappstore yes you can replace title.id by title.status. Icon you need get icon if you want and replace to above code.

Comment: I placed Assets some images by id name like "first.png" ,"second.png","third.png". here the names I am going to pass from JSON. Please update my code how to fetch it and also If I click title.status then need to print its title.id. I will update my question.

Comment: @myappstore  ok. I just help your add icon from title.icon

Comment: @myappstore everything ok?

Comment: Thanks dude. Awesome solution, you saved my time.

Comment: @myappstore no problem 

Comment: @myappstore you add break point to the line set text of resultTitle. If it not run in main queue, please use Gcd to async to main queue and put code update into

Comment: I think you should post new question to clear problem.

Comment: ok I will post it on new question. can we delete here unwanted comments. I did my side. Thanks @Thanh Vu

Comment: Post new question, please. Because it not relate with current question.

Comment: @myappstore ok. Until you post new question. I will go and help you