# UILabel text not updating inside For loop execution Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to implement based on `ActionSheet` button click to show selected button title on main viewcontroller `UILabel`. Here, below code I am using but the label `title` not updating based on actionsheet button click.

The issue happening by for loop execution. `UILabel.text not changing before last For Loop execution.` how to handle and fix it?

**ActionSheet**

```
 @IBAction func ClickAction(_ sender: Any) {
        let actionSheetAlertController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        for title in self.titleData {
            let action = UIAlertAction(title: title.status, style: .default) { (action) in
                print("Title: \(title.status)")
                print("Title: \(title.id)")
                self.resultTitle.text = title.status // not updating here.                    
            let icon = UIImage.init(named: title.icon)
            action.setValue(icon, forKey: "image")
            action.setValue(CATextLayerAlignmentMode.left, forKey: "titleTextAlignment")
            actionSheetAlertController.addAction(action)
        }
        let cancelActionButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        actionSheetAlertController.addAction(cancelActionButton)
        self.present(actionSheetAlertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

**Getting Output**

[image]

Comment: could you upload full sample project?

Comment: Set a breakpoint in your action handler to verify that it is being called. Verify that `resultTitle` is the label you think it is

Comment: @ Paulw11  i tried by breakpoint its making call but I didn't know why label not updating in a first click. If i click second time `ClickAction(_ sender: Any)` its updating.

Comment: As I see, the function seen good, maybe no problem.

Comment: The problem so weird. I can’t guess problem.

Comment: @Thanh Vu I will share my code, can you please come chat for a min

Comment: @myappstore ok. You send me sample proj. I litle busy right now.

Comment: @Thanh Vu help me on this. Still i didn't get output

Comment: @myappstore where is full sample project?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198786/discussion-between-myapp-store-and-thanh-vu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue not occured in my machine. Please restart your machine, maybe problem will resolve.

Comment: Yes. Its happened by simulator issue. Thank you so much  @Thanh Vu

Comment: @myappstore Did you try real device?

Comment: I am going to check by real device and update you here. Thanks buddy

Comment: Waiting for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the checks with action title not with the id. So, here is you solution that is working fine:

```
struct ActionOption {
  var id: String
  var title: String
  var icon: UIImage?

  static func getAll() -> [ActionOption] {
    let titleData = ["Red", "Green", "Yellow"]
    var all: [ActionOption] = []
    for (idx, ttl) in titleData.enumerated() {
        all.append(ActionOption(id: "\(idx)", title: ttl, icon: nil))
    }
    return all
  }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

  var titleData: [ActionOption] = []

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.titleData = ActionOption.getAll()
  }

  @IBAction func changeAction(_ sender: Any) {
    let actionSheetAlertController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    for title in self.titleData {
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: title.title, style: .default) { (action) in

            switch (action.title ?? "") { // you need to vhange your code here
            case "Red" :
                self.imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            case "Green" :
                self.imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
            case "Yellow" :
                self.imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
            default : self.imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
            }
        }

        action.setValue(title.icon, forKey: "image")
        action.setValue(CATextLayerAlignmentMode.left, forKey: "titleTextAlignment")
        actionSheetAlertController.addAction(action)
    }
    let cancelActionButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
    actionSheetAlertController.addAction(cancelActionButton)
    self.present(actionSheetAlertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
}
```

You need to make some changes in you `switch` statement, use the parameter closure for deciding the desired action to perform. As these closure will call when the action being perform and that time `title` for loop object will not be present/available for being used.

**Result As of Code:**

[image]

Comment: @myappstore check the updated answer.

Comment: Above solution not working. This is the issue I think `UILabel.text not changing before last For Loop execution`

Comment: @myappstore I'm using here `UIImageView` for changing the selected colour. You can use a `UILable` for the same and in cases of the switch you can set the `text` as you want.

Comment: I am loading data from JSON. I don't know how to modify your code to my scenario. Please check this link and update your code  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57731866/how-to-load-json-array-data-into-uiactionsheet-button-title-using-swift

Answer (score 0):

Just put `self.resultTitle.text = title.status` inside `DispatchQueue.main.async { }`

```
@IBAction func ClickAction(_ sender: Any) {
    let actionSheetAlertController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    for title in self.titleData { // I thik this is the plm
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: title.status, style: .default) { (action) in
            print("Title: \(title.status)")
            print("Title: \(title.id)")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.resultTitle.text = title.status
            }
        }

        let icon = UIImage.init(named: title.icon)
        action.setValue(icon, forKey: "image")
        action.setValue(CATextLayerAlignmentMode.left, forKey: "titleTextAlignment")
        actionSheetAlertController.addAction(action)
    }
    let cancelActionButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
    actionSheetAlertController.addAction(cancelActionButton)
    self.present(actionSheetAlertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: i tried this its not working